# How to detect heavy CPU usage in chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In my webapp, the little circle is causing high cpu usage in slower computers.

I slowed down my cpu in *4 to debug it and I'm able to reproduce it.

It seems that I can't figure out anything that is related to high CPU usage in the performance tab.

#### What am I missing?

(I'm a begginer with chrome devtools)

[image: spinner]

[image: DevTools]

[image: Bottom-Up tab]

Comment: Click on `Bottom-up` in the bottom tabs.

Comment: nothing is clickable there. I added a screen shot to the question.

Comment: The CPU strip at the top of the screenshot is only filled at the end so I doubt this tab is the cause of the problem. See also [Performance Analysis Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference). FWIW this can be a bug in Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm there are no other tabs open as you can see in the screen shot. also this reproduces in chromes on ubuntu and fedura. so what can i do to understand more about it?

Comment: I added a different screen shot of a longer period of time.

Comment: Try using the heavy-duty chrome://tracing tool, [more info](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/trace-event-profiling-tool).